# Questions on translating "primo tamen pessime regebat"

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation, sentence-translation

I came across the sentence (in the title) and I am confused about the translation of "tamen". Tamen means however but when I put it on google translate (ignoring its inaccuracy), it didn't even translate the "tamen". Also, "pessime" here seems to be an adverb right? Can someone please give me a nice youtube link about adverbs? (I can't just use the adjective conjugation and say it's abl. or smth can I?)

Comment: If you know what *tamen* means why does it matter that a machine translation service that you know is bad at translating Latin doesn't translate it?

Comment: For Google Translate, make sure to end your sentences with a full stop. Without full stop: "At first he ruled very badly". With full stop: "At first, however, he ruled very badly." Please don't ask me why this is so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, Google Translate shouldn't be trusted. Second, *tamen* is a contrastive adverb that often has the force of a conjunction. The sentence reads something like: "At first, however, he was ruling very badly" or more naturally "Yet at first he was ruling very poorly."

For most three-termination adjectives (those ending in -us, -a, -um), all you need to make an adverb is to drop the ending and replace it with a long -e. For two-termination adjectives (-is, -e), you use instead -(i)ter; thus *leviter* from *levis, -is*.

There are certain circumstances in which an adjective in the ablative or accusative case gets used essentially like an adverb, and *primo* here is one of them. There are a handful of words you'll see that frequently do this, and Allen and Greenough have a short list of them [here](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/derivation-adverbs).

Answer (score 5):

*Pessime* is indeed the adverb of *pessimus* 'worst, very bad', which is the superlative of *malus* 'bad', so it translates very straightforwardly as 'worstly' or 'very badly', as you would expect.

*Conor* is a [**deponent** verb](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/deponent-verbs), which means it has passive morphology but active or middle/reflexive meaning.

Comment: Now I want to know whether *optime* means "bestly" or "wellest" ;-)

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Wait, it's not "goodestly"?